# add string to end of awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

how do i add an echo command after a AWK statement?
i have a string variable and want to add a word to the end of it.
i am writing this in a script and do not want to create/save to any files.
another possibility would be if i could save the output from the echo command into a local variable for later use.

```
my_value="the second player is the winner"
echo "$my_value" | awk '{sub(/winner/,"first loser.")}1' | 'Unless they win'
```

is it possible to add a word/variable to the end of the echo command?
so the output would look like this.

```
the second player is the first loser. Unless they win
```

updated:

if i have a string like above and i wanted to change second player to first player also add another echo command to end. This is what i meant earlier.

'''

my_value1="unless they lose"

my_value="the second player is the winner"

echo "$my_value" | awk '{sub(/second/,"first")}1' | $my_value1

'''

is it easier to use a second variable or input another echo " " with the words?

Comment: so use `sub(/winner/,"first loser unless they win")`

Comment: Or forget `awk` and just `echo ${myvalue/winner/first loser unless they win}` using the built-in *parameter expansion with substring replacement* that bash provides.

Comment: `echo "$my_value" | awk '{sub(/winner/,"first loser"); printf $0} END{printf " %s\n", "unless they win"}'`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin or just plain POSIX string expansion `echo "${myvalue%winner}first loser unless they win"`

Comment: Yes, that would be an excellent choice as well.

Answer (score 0):

or why not do as you said yourself:

```
kg$ echo "$my_value unless they win" | awk '{sub(/winner/,"first loser")}1'
```

the second player is the first loser unless they win